# Many-to-many that shows columns with null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having some difficulty trying to figure how to adjust my query. I'm not very good at SQL queries as it's not my forte. Anyway, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my table setup.

```
ID | Customer
---+-------------
1  | John
2  | Jane
3  | Steve


ID | Assets
---+-------------
1  | RealEstate
2  | Currency
3  | Stocks


CustomerID | AssetConfigurationId | Status
-----------+----------------------+-------
     1     |           1          |  E
     1     |           2          |  F
     1     |           3          |  X
     2     |           3          |  X
```

And if I query customer = 3, I want to get the following

```
AssetConfigurationId | Status
---------------------+------------
         1           | null
         2           | null
         3           | X
```

Currently have this. I'm trying to understand how I can use left join to show all the assets and just have the values of the statuses to null for a specific customer. Right now it only shows the 3rd row. Trying to do this in a SQL Server stored procedure so that my .net application can get a list of the assets already and I'll just modify the statuses when it comes to converting them to objects.

```
select
    ac.Id,
    r.Status
from 
    assets ac
left join 
    assets_ref r on r.AssetConfigurationId = ac.Id
where 
    r.CustomerID = 3
```

Comment: How come your result become null.. but your table has a value like the value of 1 and 2.

Comment: what do you mean for 1 and 2.. it should be set to `null`? and `3 = x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `WHERE` condition in the inner query.

```
select
    ac.Id,
    r.Status
from assets ac
left join 
(select * from assets_ref where CustomerID = 3) r 
on r.AssetConfigurationId = ac.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple conditions in `JOIN`s:

```
select
    ac.Id,
    r.Status
from assets ac
left join assets_ref r
    on r.AssetConfigurationId = ac.Id
    and CustomerID = 3;
```